Execute bash command from QLM KDE-Plasma Widget
I am trying to create a widget within KDE Plasma that enables me to quickly mount an drive via rClone. Meaning I have an icon in my task bar from which I can select what drives to mount. However I did not find a way to execute a bash command from an QLM file.
What i have:
I have a bash command that mounts a OneDrive folder with rClone.
// Example:
rclone mount remote:path/to/files /path/to/local/mount

What i want:
I want to create a shortcut (preferably in the taskbar, like an KDE Widget) on which I can click that fires the mentioned command (mount).
What I tried:
I created a Widget which I added to the Taskbar. It has a button that should fire mentioned command (like the following).
PlasmaComponents.Button {
   text: i18n("Mount")
   onClicked: ???
}

The problem:
That's where I am stuck. How can I execute a bash command on button click in an Plasma widget (written in QLM)? Is there some library/plugin/api to do this? Or is there a completely different way of achieving this or something similar?

Why QLM? Why not just write the script as save it as a text file (include the #!/bin/bash) make it executable (chmod 0755 /path/to/yourscript) and then create an icon (a .desktop file) using kmenuedit that uses your script as the executable and then just put the application icon in your taskbar? You can even include dialogs from your script using kdialog to provide a confirmation dialog showing the mount succeeds, etc...

See KDE Menu Editor Handbook You can also use kdialog to present a KDE dialog (Yes, No, Cancel, etc..) that will do what you want.

@DavidC.Rankin Thanks for pointing me towards kmenuedit and kdialog, I can definitely make use of that.

Glad it helped! I've used KDE for over 20 years now and usually just think about the easy way to get something done :). Good to know the QLM approach will also work, though admittedly, I've not ventured into it yet. Good luck with your scripting. (always remember to paste all scripts into ShellCheck to make sure you haven't missed anything). It is a fantastic tool that is quite helpful, even for those that have been scripting for decades.

Thanks for suggesting ShellCheck, i‘ll check it out! I am quite new to both QLM and Shell Scripting, so i think it cam help me a lot.

DavidC.Rankin pointed me towards kmenuedit (and kdialog), which is an easier way of achiving this. However, I also found an answer to my original question:
On another site a user provided me with an answer that i want to share here. It is indeed possible to run bash commands from QLM Widgets:

Assuming you're using Plasma 6, you should be able to do this via a
"DataSource".
If you look at the code for the Toggle Overview Widget for Plasma 6,
when you go to the code, you can see how it's being used. I've
actually utilized the relevant code myself for one of my own modified
widgets.
What you need to do is import org.kde.plasma.plasma5support as
Plasma5Support and then setup the Plasma5Support.DataSource from there
(check the code, should be from line 81 - 92 as of the time of writing
this). If you use the code from there then you should be able to use
the following:
executable.exec('bash command goes here');

You could also put the exec in a function and then call that function
when the button is clicked.

(From Reddit)
To summarize: you need to
import org.kde.plasma.plasma5support as Plasma5Support

and then add the button and the DataSource to the Widget:
PlasmaComponents.Button {
    text: i18n("Execute")
    onClicked: executable.exec('bash_code_here')
}

Plasma5Support.DataSource {
    id: executable
    engine: "executable"
    connectedSources: []
    onNewData: function(source, data) {
        disconnectSource(source)
    }

    function exec(cmd) {
        executable.connectSource(cmd)
    }
}

Alternatively, you can also execute a script file:
onClicked: executable.exec('bash /path/to/yourscript')

